# Set and Get accessors are not working for my angular component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I don't know why set & get accessors does not change anything in the value of _counter property? 
when i use **this.propagateChange** method in the **set** accessor it will not working, but when i used it inside **incr()** and **decr()** methods it worked correctly, so what is the problem please?

here is my codes :

**button.component.ts**

```
import {Component, forwardRef, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-button',
  templateUrl: './button.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./button.component.scss'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => ButtonComponent),
      multi: true,
    }
  ]
})
export class ButtonComponent implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor {
  _counter  = 0;
  @Input() step = 1;
  propagateChange;

  get counter() {
    return this._counter ;
  }

  set counter(value) {
    this._counter  = value;
    this.propagateChange(this._counter);
  }

  setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean): void {
  }

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  incr() {
    this._counter  += this.step;
  }

  decr() {
    this._counter  -= this.step;
    /*this.propagateChange(this._counter);*/
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: any) {
    this.propagateChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
  }

  writeValue(obj: any): void {
    if (obj !== undefined) {
      this._counter  = obj;
    }
  }
}
```

**button.component.html**

```
<button (click)="incr()">+</button>
<button (click)="decr()">-</button>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  prodForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder
  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.prodForm = this.fb.group(
      {
        counter: [0, Validators.required]
      }
    );
  }


}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="prodForm">
  <input [value]="prodForm.get('counter').value">
  <app-button formControlName="counter"></app-button>
</form>
```

Thanks.

Comment: In incr and decr function, you wrote this._counter, not this.counter, so don't pass to the setter function

Comment: it still not working ..

Comment: you can check my solution @Eliseo here :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60020655/8678900

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by changing this line :

```
export class ButtonComponent implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor {
  _counter = 0;
  @Input() step = 1;
  propagateChange; ===> this is the problem
..
...
....
```

to this one:

```
export class ButtonComponent implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor {
  _counter = 0;
  @Input() step = 1;
propagateChange: any = () => {}; ===> this is the answer
..
...
....
```

In addition to [@Kamil Augustyniak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9552890/kamil-augustyniak) ==> [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60018803/8678900), I solved it.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `_counter` only inside getter and setter. Outside you have to use `counter`.

```
export class ButtonComponent implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor {
  _counter = 0;
  @Input() step = 1;
  propagateChange;

  get counter() {
    return this._counter;
  }

  set counter(value) {
    this._counter = value;
    this.propagateChange(this._counter);
  }

  setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean): void {
  }

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  incr() {
    this.counter += this.step;
  }

  decr() {
    this.counter -= this.step;
    /*this.propagateChange(this._counter);*/
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: any) {
    this.propagateChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
  }

  writeValue(obj: any): void {
    if (obj !== undefined) {
      this.counter = obj;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you tell difference between this.counter and this. _counter here?

Comment: If you want to add extra logic during changing or getting property value, you can use getter and setter so we need a property to keep correct data (in this case `_counter`). Even, It should be private because we shouldn't modify it outside component. Extra logic can be run only when we operate on getter/setter name so in this case, we can't use `_counter` outside setter, we have to use `counter` and `this.propagateChange(this._counter);` will be executed too.

Comment: Have you uncommented it? `/*this.propagateChange(this._counter);*/`

Answer (score 0):

You have to reference this.counter = yourvalue ;

But you're referencing this._counter

Comment: it still not working even if i change the reference to this.counter = myvalue;